# What is the maximum weight could 26 1 3/8 tire and tube could withstand?

Tags: puncture, rear-wheel, weight

I bought my first bike few months ago, and it is old Raleigh 26" 1 -3/8 size. 
Every time I go with this bike through some bumps the rear tire and inner tube get punctured with large hole.

It is written in the tire that the maximum weight is 70Kg and I am 80Kg.

Is it the quality of the inner tube and tire makes it vulnerable to puncture? (we only have some cheap chinese tires and tubes in my country)

Or the size will not fit with my weight?
Or I can find a 26" tire and tube that could hold my weight?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the maximum weight is 70kg? That's ridiculously low and would make the tyre unusable by most adults.

Comment: Yes I am sure, it is written on it. It is my first bike and in our market it is very difficult to find many brands. I find only two brands and with the same weight.

Comment: have you come cross a 26" 1 3/8 tyre with different withstand weight? I searched on tires in Amazon and didn't mention any thing about the weight.

Comment: Does your air pump have a pressure gauge?   If so, please tell us what pressure you're pumping your tyre up to, in PSI or bar or whatever unit.

Comment: Chinese tubes are fine - they tend to be overly thick to make up for slightly lower-grade materials.  This helps reduce punctures, at the cost of added weight.

Comment: Also work on your riding technique - avoid bashing through potholes like you're an army tank.  Instead skirt them, or bunny hop them, or at least unweight the bike so it has less force on the impact.

Comment: 26" 1 -3/8   is a funny size - can you please check the sidewall of the tyre for the ETRTO measurement?  Should be a number of the format xx-yyy eg   53-538 or 35-530 or similar.

Comment: What is the air pressure you are putting in the tire.  Your description of punctures when hitting bumps screams "THE TIRE PRESSURE IS TOO LOW!!!"

Comment: @Criggie the size is 37-590 and I don't have a pressure gauge.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, If the pressure is low, will I get large puncture in the tire and inner tube in the side wall when I hit bumps?

Comment: Side comment, that is not a common 26" wheel, what would say xx-559 on it.  A 590 is what is called a 650A wheel or a *26" x 1 3/8* which is larger than a common modern 26" wheel.   No wonder you're having problems finding tyres for it.

Comment: @AshrafAlmubarak - There are lots of variables.  Depends on the bump, the shape of the rim, the thickness of the tire, and the material used in the tube.  (But, basically, if, when you squeeze the tire with your fingers and you can compress it at all, the pressure is too low.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks, generally speaking the smaller tires are more vulnerable to puncture, isn't it?

Comment: @AshrafAlmubarak - A smaller tire needs a higher inflation pressure to safely carry the same load.  This makes it more vulnerable to underinflation.

Comment: Until now I didn't get a clear vision to the problem. Most of people say it is under pressure may cause the puncture. But does under pressure cause a puncture of 10 mm size? Or it is caused by over pressure? Or just the tire quality is not ok? Or my weight don't fit the tire size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not putting 80 kg of weight on either tire; you're putting 80 kg + bike weight (say, 15 kg) on both tires combined, probably about 60% on the back, 40% on the front. So, about 57 kg on the back. In any case, I doubt very much that your weight is making you more susceptible to flats.
2. The quality of the inner tube doesn't affect puncture resistance very much. The tire does determine puncture resistance. Some tires are engineered for light weight, some for flat resistance, some to meet a price point.
3. One important cause of flats is under-inflation, which can happen with any kind of tire or tube. This permits the tire to bottom out against the rim when you hit a bump, causing what's called a "snakebite flat." So a first step towards preventing flats is ensuring adequate inflation. Here's an [inflation calculator](http://engineeredinsanity.com/clydesdale-how-to-estimate-tire-pressure/).
4. The other main cause of flats, as you might imagine, is road debris. There's not a lot we can do about that other than try to avoid it. If I unavoidably ride through a patch of broken glass, I'll try to wipe down my tire with my (gloved) hand immediately after, but realistically, the damage is probably already done. If you think this is a likely culprit, you might try tire liners, which fit between the tire and inner tube and provide an extra layer of protection.

Comment: 3. The puncture occurred in the side wall of the tire. is this caused by under inflation too?

Comment: 1. I have 3 times flat and all of them in the rear tire. Is it possible the design of the bike makes be put more weight in the rear tire? Because when I ride it I notice the rear tire is affected by my weight while the front doesn't do that much.

Comment: All conventional bikes put more weight on the rear tire, and flats on the rear are much more common in general. A sidewall flat could be a snakebite flat.

Comment: ok thanks I will maintain the right tire pressure and see the results.

Comment: I used the tire pressure calculator and gave me a pressure of 60 psi and it is written on my tire max pressure 50 psi.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for new tires!

Comment: A puncture on the side wall is most likely a cut caused by debris (glass and metal mostly! but also thorns, flint and other sharp stones)

Comment: @AshrafAlmubarak Sounds like your tire was designed for kids, not adults. 60 psi is about the minimum pressure rating for quality tires of that size (they can take up to 90 or 100 psi max). So, get some real tire, inflate it to some real pressure, and your problems will be gone.

Comment: @cmaster I try to find a one with 60 psi, although it will be difficult in the market.

Comment: I agree with the advice to check your tyres after riding through glass, because the damage _hasn't_ necessarily already been done. I once punctured because I didn't notice riding through glass and thought the tick-tick-tick of a shard hitting the road every wheel revolution was something like a leaf stuck in my mudguard. The ticking stopped quite quickly but, a couple of miles later, I punctured because the glass got pushed right through to the inner tube. If I'd stopped immediately, the glass would have only caused superficial damage to the tyre.

Answer (score 2):

Minor point but you state the bike is old.  There's nothing wrong with that, but its quite possible that the tyres and tubes are also old.

Sunlight, heat, and ozone do damage to rubber over time.

Rubber parts perish with age, meaning they loose strength.  So a tube might inflate okay but not cope with the peak force of a bump.

- If you can tear the tube using your arms, its old and needs replacing.
- If the tyre has excessive cracking, looks dry or brittle, or you can see the canvas because of wear or flakes falling off, replace the tyres.
- If your braking is bad, replace the brake blocks/pads.  They can look perfect but be hardened and no longer provide predictable friction to the rims.

All these parts are "wear" parts, aka consumables.  So if the bike fits you and is mechanically sound, is worth looking after it with basic refresh like this.

Comment: I changed the tire and tube 3 times with new one.

Comment: @AshrafAlmubarak okay thanks - then this answer does not address the cause of your problems.    Need a pressure reading - perhaps you can borrow a pressure gauge ?  Does the local service station have one on their air pump ?

Comment: I will try to find a pressure gauge that fits bike valve size, it is easy to find a pressure gauge for car tires. Bike tires pressure gauge will be very difficult.

Comment: Until now I didn't get a clear vision to the problem. Most of people say it is under pressure may cause the puncture. But does under pressure cause a puncture of 10 mm size? Or it is caused by over pressure? Or just the tire quality is not ok? Or my weight don't fit the tire size?

Comment: Get a pressure reading, lets figure out whether the pressure in the tyres is okay or too low.   Perhaps try a bike shop, or ask a fellow cyclist in your neighbourhood?  Or talk to your bike shop.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, its most likely a 'Snake bite', as covered by @Adam #3. Where are the holes? Does the tube have two holes or marks close together (hence the name "Snakebite" ).

The next most likely possibility is you have something sticking though the tire or rattling around loose inside the tire. When you remove the tire and tube, pay attention to where the tire is in relation to the valve (mark it if needed). When you find the hole, look inside the tire at this place for something stuck in the tire.

When you put the tire on, align a label with the tube valve so the tire/tube is in the same place. This is done so if you get another puncture, and its in the same place as an earlier one, you know you probably missed the thing causing the puncture.

Don't write off just plain old bad luck. I once punctured 3 times in less than 6km... Sometime it just decides that today is not your day....

Comment: The holes in the side wall of the tire and tube, and they are large holes.